# How to remove extra and leading spaces

Tags: c++, whitespace

The requirement of my assignment is writing this function (I can have another function):

```
void process (char input[], char output[]){

}
```

**And the given `main()` is:**

```
int main(){
    const int MAX_SIZE = 100;
    char input[] = " abc  def  ghi ";
    char output[MAX_SIZE];
    process(input, output);
    cout << input;
    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE:** The available library are: `<cstring>` and `<iostream>`

**I have written two function:**

```
void erase(char str[], int location){
    int len = strlen(str);
    for (int i = location; i < len; i++){
        str[i] = str[i+1];
    }
}

void process(char input[], char output[]){
    
    //eraseSpaces(str);
    int outIndex = 0, strIndex = 0;
    int n = strlen(input);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        output[outIndex] = input[strIndex];

        if (input[i] == ' ' && input[i+1] == ' '){
            erase(str, i);
            i--;
        }
        
        if(input[0] == ' '){
            erase(str, 0);
        }
       
        if(input[n-1] == ' '){
            erase(str, n-1);
        }

        outIndex++;
        strIndex--;
    }
    output[outIndex] = '\0'; //ket thuc
}
```

However, this doesn't work well. I want the result to be `"abc def ghi"`, but the result isn't what I want.

How should I fix it?

Comment: If you're using C++, the simplest way is a 3 line program using `std::string` and `std::stringstream`.

Comment: Note that, inexplicably, the given `main` prints `input`, not `output`. Was it meant this way? Are you supposed to modify `input` in-place, and if so, what's `output` supposed to be for?

Comment: I cannot find definition of `str` in `process()`. What is the `str` ?

Comment: Why is this tagged as `fix-protocol`?

Comment: Don't use "C" style arrays for strings use std::string as said, and then there are nice functions like [find_first_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) to help you implement this. Or use the code in my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75242996/c-split-char-array-without-use-of-any-library/75243052#75243052) to split your input into smaller strings (use space as delimiter).  So you only end up with three string(_view)s `abc`, `def`, `ghi`. And then that is easy to reformat

Comment: to various commenters - OP says only iostream and cstring can be used, so no std::string, no stringstream... etc

Comment: you do not need erase, just dont copy the characters you dont need

Comment: also strIndex starts out at 0 and you then decrement it, thats not going to work at all.

Comment: @PepijnKramer `std::string` can be a lot slower compared to C strings because of all the mandatory dynamic allocation, in particular on the constructors without cow since c++11.

Comment: I know std::string is slower, it is an engineering tradeoff everyone has to make for him/her self. Maintainability/readability vs. speed. The other option I use is std::string_view.  The bad thing is `char*` by itself doesn't promise to be a `\0` terminated string (and doesn't denote ownership either). If it points to a buffer, there is no way of knowing the size. All those are reasons for me to no longer use "C" style arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The function signature does not do what you might think it does. If you want to take only statically sized arrays (along with their sizes), I recommend this:

```
template<std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
void process(char const (&input)[N], char (&output)[M])
```

**However**, to process c-like strings, skipping *only initial spaces*, you can do this much easier even without including `<cstring>`.

```
void process(char const* input, char* output) {
    while (*input == ' ') ++input; // skip leading spaces
    while ((*output++ = *input++)) {} // copy rest, including '\0'
}
```

Edit: If you want to skip also all redundant spaces within the words it is slightly more involved, but similar in structure to the previous function:

```
void process(char const* input, char* output) {
    auto const chunk = [](char const c) { return (c != ' ') & (c != 0);};
    do {
      while (*input == ' ') ++input; // skip superfluous spaces
      while (chunk((*output++ = *input++))) {} // copy until 0 or space (inclusive)
    } while (*(input-1));
}
```

Comment: It looks like that consecutive spaces between words should be reduced to a single space.

Comment: @fana Oh, I failed to notice that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do everything at once and can't figure out what's wrong, I recommend to do step by step.
For example...

As the first try, simply copying non-space chars only.

```cpp
void process( const char input[], char output[] )
{
    const char *pIn = input;
    char *pOut = output;
    while( *pIn )
    {
        //push only non space char
        if( *pIn != ' ' )
        {
            *pOut++ = *pIn;
        }
        ++pIn;
    }
    *pOut = '\0';
}
```

The result is `"abcdefghi"`. This is current desired result. Good.

Now I want to insert space between words.
So, add the process to do it.

```cpp
void process( const char input[], char output[] )
{
    const char *pIn = input;
    char *pOut = output;
    while( *pIn )
    {
        if( *pIn != ' ' )
        {
            //push a space if previous input char is space
            if(
                   ( pIn != input ) //"previous" is existing
                && ( *(pIn-1)==' ' )    //"previous" is space
                )
            {   *pOut++ = ' ';  }

            *pOut++ = *pIn;
        }
        ++pIn;
    }
    *pOut = '\0';
}
```

And result becomes to `" abc def ghi"`.
Oh, first space!
Current code is "add space before each words", not "insert space between words"!

I understood mistake. Therefore modify the condition of the `if` :

```cpp
void process( const char input[], char output[] )
{
    const char *pIn = input;
    char *pOut = output;
    while( *pIn )
    {
        if( *pIn != ' ' )
        {
            if(
                   ( pIn != input  &&  *(pIn-1)==' ' )  //previous input char is space
                && ( pOut != output )   //not first output
            )
            {   *pOut++ = ' ';  }

            *pOut++ = *pIn;
        }
        ++pIn;
    }
    *pOut = '\0';
}
```

Now I obtain the good result `"abc def ghi"`. It looks like good.

Then test with other inputs, and if something wrong... modify...

Answer (score 0):

A C++ take with string_view (it requires C++17)

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

void process ( const char input[], char output[]){
    std::string_view sin(input);
    auto start = sin.find_first_not_of(' ');
    if ( start != std::string_view::npos ) {
        auto finish = sin.find_last_not_of(' ');
        output += sin.copy( output, finish-start+1, start );
    }
    *output = '\0';
}

int main(){
    const int MAX_SIZE = 100;
    char input[] = " abc  def  ghi ";
    char output[MAX_SIZE];
    process(input, output);
    std::cout << "[" << input << "]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "[" << output << "]" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/vMafoM95T

Produces:

```bash
Program stdout
[ abc  def  ghi ]
[abc  def  ghi]
```

And a pure-C take

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void process ( const char input[], char output[]){
    const char* p = input;
    for ( ;(*p!='\0')&&(*p==' '); p++ );          // Find first not a char
    const char* endp = p;                         // Save for later
    for ( ;*endp!='\0'; endp++ );                 // Find the string's end
    for ( ;(p<endp)&&(*(endp-1)==' '); endp-- );  // Find back the last non whitespace
    for ( ;p<endp; p++ ) *output++ = *p;          // Copy to output
    *output++ = '\0';                             // Mark end
}

int main(){
    const int MAX_SIZE = 100;
    char input[] = " abc  def  ghi ";
    char output[MAX_SIZE];
    process(input, output);
    printf( "[%s]\n", input );
    printf( "[%s]\n", output );
    return 0;
}
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/hThe1rcW6

Produces:

```bash
Program stdout
[ abc  def  ghi ]
[abc  def  ghi]
```

Comment: I missed it at first, too, but OP wanted redundant white space *inside* the string removed as well. That is between 'c' and 'd' and between 'f' and 'g'.